# Node.js small command-line program and storing data persistently

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, coffeescript, storage

I'm writing a small desktop app using CoffeeScript and node - not a webapp or anything - completely synchronous. And I'd like it to have a dotfolder in which I can store some persisten user data - In particular, I'd like to store some JSON objects, and some image files (I don't know if you can read an image file and convert it to some JSON object so it's all just a case of saving JSON data). I was going about this with `fs` and writing some custom reading and writing of JSON files, but then tried to look for a better way of doing it. So I tried Google-fu, but a lot of resources that come up are oriented towards web-apps (understandably!). So, how can I do this well, using existing tools, without writing a load of custom js that just uses `fs`?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You can save images/files as Base64 strings... in a json file is it's really necessary... But keep in mind that doing so will make file loading much longer and could make it impossible if the file gets big enough. Base64 encoded binary files usually take 30% more space than simple binary file.

Comment: The cmdline utility I'm making takes several text files (.md and the like), and processes them, and then outputs them. I want the cmdline utility to save content of such textfiles for later, which is easy, just save to json or something and put in the dotfolder. But since such files often link to images, I'd like to save any image files with them, without overcomplicating directory structure that might get violated. I thought some local DB storage solution would be better, or sticking the image in the rest of the json as a string.

Comment: You could do that by hosting a database server such as CouchDB. Push the files to the server and get them when necessary using PouchDB from the command line. It might be much easier than reinventing the wheel and implement a database by yourself if you have somewhat complicated set of data that you want to store.

Comment: `fs` is used the same way in a webapp or command-line application. You need to write your code like you would do with a program written in a "desktop" language (C++/Java/C#...). There is no `main()` though so you just write your code directly in your js file (you can use functions and multiple files to organize your code). The resources you found for webapps apply easily to a command-line application, just remove anything related to webserver (port listening, request and response handling, routing...).